# Is the result of (every) research on acceleration equivalent to gravity?

Tags: gravity, acceleration, popular-science, equivalence-principle

Is the result of an experiment on acceleration equivalent to another experiment in a gravitational field?

If I have an experimental conclusion from research under uniform acceleration, can the conclusion be extended to apply to gravity too?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): One difference is that gravity in general produces [tidal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force), while (linear) acceleration doesn't.

Comment: @Qmechanic: This version of the equivalence principle is local. Tidal effects are nonlocal in the sense that when you restrict to a region of size $L$, they vanish like a higher power of $L$ than the effect of gravity itself. Similar considerations apply to curvature, which is not equivalent to an acceleration of a flat spacetime.

Comment: @Qmechanic well.... if I'm on a centripetal station in orbit, i Do experience tidal effects in a sense, because the force is not exactly the same everywhere near me. There is also some dependence of speed, which is not present on gravity forces, that I'm aware

Answer (score 3):

Well, one statement of the equivalence principle is that acceleration in the absence of gravity cannot, with any experiment, be distinguished from remaining at rest in a gravitational field.